# My plugin won't return anything

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I am trying to write a simple plugin to insert some post links in a post at the right place.

The query part works okay in a template, but my attempt at a displaying via plugin just returns a blank space.

```
//tell wordpress to register the wafunitslist shortcode
add_shortcode("waf-units-list", "wafunitslist_handler");

function wafunitslist_handler() {
    wafunitslist_function();
}

function wafunitslist_function() {
?>
<?php $country = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Country", true); ?>
<?php $operator = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Operator", true); ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=738&meta_key=Operator&meta_value='.$operator.'&orderby=title&posts_per_page=-1&order=ASC' ); ?>

<?php
   // Reset and setup variables
   $output = '';
   $temp_title = '';
   $temp_link = '';

   // the loop
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      $temp_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
      $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);

      // output all findings - CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR LIKING
      $output .= '<li><a href="'.$temp_link.'">'.$temp_title.'</a></li>';

   endwhile; else:

      $output .= 'nothing found';

   endif;

   wp_reset_query();
   return $output;
}

?>
```

Replacing 'return' by 'echo' shows a list of links at the top of the post, but 'return' gives nothing.
What am I doing wrong?  This is driving me a bit crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a 'return' from your shortcode handler:

```
function wafunitslist_handler() {
    return wafunitslist_function();
}
```